# Java Regex - Match the "word" which may or may not be starting with xyz

Tags: java, regex

Find the exact match of "word" in a string which may have a prefix of xyz .

Example :

> My word is a cool xyzword butword .

The matches should be

> My **word** is a cool xyz**word** butword .

The max solution is came up with

> \b([xyz]*word)\b

But it gives xyzword also as a match

Comment: *But it gives xyzword also as a match* - isn't that what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should give what you're awaiting

```
(?<=\b|\bxyz)word(?=\b)
```

It matches all the "word" that have either a word boundary, or `xyz` before and a word boundary after

Comment: nice answer you can argument your answer with this demo [`(?<=\b|xyz)word`](https://regex101.com/r/yNkER1/1)

Comment: However, [it also matches `word` in `moreherexyzword`](https://regex101.com/r/yNkER1/3), too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in this case you can use [`(?<=\b|\bxyz)word(?=\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/yNkER1/4)

Comment: Yes, but it is much easier with `\b(xyz)?(word)\b`, but I have no idea what OP is doing, extracting or replacing. More, you do not have to use `(?=\b)`, `\b` is itself a zero-width assertion.

Comment: I was actually wanted to use `&lt`  instead of xyz .  But even after escaping the ampersand in java it's still not working. Can any one help with this?

Comment: @Sanket9394 You can ask a new question if it's a different problem :)

Comment: @YassinHajaj it's 90% similar to this one. except that `&lt` part . The new questions might be flagged as an duplicate